# SWIFT - TableView showing comments

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield

I have unsuccessfully searched an answer to this question and it possibly has to do with the fact that i'm not entirely sure what to ask as i'm somewhat new to programming.

What I'm trying to implement is a comments section in my app (much like instagram's comment tableview) but with a footer where user can add to the comments. I'm not sure how one would go about this.

I imagine having a ViewController with a tableView on top of it - effectively having to implement the tableview delegate and datasource. But from here, how would one add a footer-like section that allows the user to input a comment and then append to the tableView?

FYI - I am using Parse for this app to store my data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about having 2 sections? (If you're not using more than one sections already) you can create different cells let's say a comment cell and a normal cell and use one for the first section and the other for the other one. (Not sure if the comment is for the whole table or for each row..?)

Comment: @vale Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into it. That shouldn't affect the cell (1st section) being able to append correct? So if for example there are 5 comments, the first section will show 5 rows of comments and the 2nd section will still be the textfield and button ("send" button to post the comment)

Comment: for what I understand you have the first row which is the content you get from parse I suppose and after you want a row for each comment and after the text field and such or it's just a page for comments?

Comment: It's a page for comments but with the option for the user to add a comment at the bottom (basically what you see with the Instagram app, where users go to comment on a photo).

Comment: Ah, ok. You can either do as I said or just have a table view at the top and a simple view at the bottom, I did something similar but for a header. Footer should be the same. Just remember to add a new row to the table when you create a comment.

Comment: @vale yeah that is what I'm currently working with. I have 1 prototype cell and I added a "view" below my cell. Would you have a recommendation as to how I would add a new row to the table whenever a comment is added?

Comment: You can use 'void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation' to add a row at a specific index path with an animation, of course remember to update your data source too.